# Service worker offline support with pushstate and client side routing

Tags: javascript, html, service-worker

I'm using a service worker to introduce offline functionality for my single page web app. It's pretty straightforward - use the network when available, or try and fetch from the cache if not:

service-worker.js:

```
self.addEventListener("fetch", event => {
    if(event.request.method !== "GET") {
        return;
    }
    event.respondWith(
        fetch(event.request)
            .then(networkResponse => {
                var responseClone = networkResponse.clone();
                if (networkResponse.status == 200) {
                    caches.open("mycache").then(cache => cache.put(event.request, responseClone));
                }
            return networkResponse;
        })
        .catch(_ => {
            return caches.match(event.request);
        })
    )
})
```

So it intercepts all GET requests and caches them for future use, including the initial page load.

Switching to "offline" in DevTools and refreshing at the root of the application works as expected.

However, my app uses HTML5 pushstate and a client side router. The user could navigate to a new route, then go offline, then hit refresh, and will get a "no internet" message, because the service worker was never told about this new URL.

I can't think of a way around it. As with most SPAs, my server is configured to serve the index.html for a number of catch-all URLs. I need some sort of similar behaviour for the service worker.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Inside your `fetch` handler, you need to check whether `event.request.mode` is set to `'navigate'`. If so, it's a navigation, and instead of responding with a cached response that matches the specific URL, you can respond with a cached response for your `index.html`. (Or `app-shell.html`, or whatever URL you use for the generic HTML for your SPA.)

Your updated `fetch` handler would look roughly like:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  if (event.request.method !== 'GET') {
    return;
  }

  if (event.request.mode === 'navigate') {
    event.respondWith(caches.match('index.html'));
    return;
  }

  // The rest of your fetch handler logic goes here.
});
```

This is a common use case for service workers, and if you'd prefer to use a pre-packaged solution, the [`NavigationRoute` class](https://workboxjs.org/reference-docs/latest/module-workbox-routing.NavigationRoute.html#main) in the [`workbox-routing` module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/workbox-routing) can automate it for you.

Comment: This is _exactly_ what I was looking for.

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/module-workbox-routing.NavigationRoute for a currently functional URL about the class: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/module-workbox-routing.NavigationRoute and https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/module-workbox-routing for the parent module.